# Is it true that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1 f_n(x) dx=\int_0^1\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x) dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f_n(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+n^2x^2};n\in \Bbb N;x\in \Bbb R$.

Is it true that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1 f_n(x) dx=\int_0^1\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x) dx$?

$f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)=$\begin{cases} 1 & x=0 \\ 0 &x\neq 0\end{cases}

But $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1 f_n(x) dx=\lim(\tan^{-1} nx)|_0^1=\lim \tan^{-1}(n)=\tan^{-1}(\frac{\pi}{2})\neq \int_0^1 f(x) dx$

Am I right?

Please check.

Comment: The antiderivative of $f_n$ would be $\frac{\tan^{-1}(nx)}{n}$.

Comment: In this case you can apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: @agb;right ;then how to do $\lim\dfrac{\tan^{-1}}{n}$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true. Note that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1 \dfrac{1}{1+n^2x^2} dx=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left[\frac{\arctan(nx)}{n}\right]_0^1=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\arctan(n)}{n}=0$$
where in the last step we used the fact that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\arctan(n)=\pi/2$.
Moreover
$$\int_0^1 f(x) dx=0$$
where $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{1}{1+n^2x^2}=f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & x=0 \\ 0 &x \not= 0\end{cases}.$$

Comment: @Rishabh Pant Any more doubts?